# Difference between いただけますか vs できますか

Tags: grammar, meaning, giving-and-receiving

So I want to say, "then can you show me your face?" politely in Japanese. I'm a newbie learner.

I'd normally go with, "それでは顔を見せることができますか" or alternatively "それでは顔を見せますか"
But I've heard a Japanese person say, "それでは顔を見せていただけますか."

So my question is, are my examples unusable? What's the difference amongst all of them? And how polite are they?

Comment: Are you just asking about the relative politeness levels or do you also not understand the grammar behind 見せていただけますか?

Comment: I'd appreciate a grammatical explanation behind 見せていただけますか and where that いただけます phrase comes from and then the politeness comparsion between that and what I originally thought if possible, and also perhaps which one is the most suitable in a friendly context. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I recommend you find some tutorials on giving and receiving verbs.

見せていただけますか is the verb 見せる in the te-form + the verb いただく in the potential form + the question particle.

いただく is the humble version of もらう and both verbs mean "to receive". When added to the te-form of a verb they mean "receive the favour of someone doing ...". So 見せていただけますか is literally "can I receive the favour of you showing me" or more sensibly "please show me". Basically you are asking someone to do something **for you**.

顔を見せることができますか is simply "Are you able to show your face?" and 顔を見せますか is "will you show your face?". Certainly they're both less polite, but whether there's a situation in which you could use them in your intended context, I'll leave to someone more knowledgeable.

Comment: Okay thank you. I already knew and used 貰う, just did not know いただく was the polite version of it. With your explanation, now I totally got it.

Comment: Then I guess we can also say, 見せてもらえ ますか as a less polite alternative.